# Android notifyDataSetChanged not refreshing the items after removing

Tags: android, listview, sparse-matrix, notifydatasetchanged

So I am trying to remove the itempending however it does not remove it from the listview immediately on click. I have to go back and come back to this screen and it will be removed. However my other listview on the same screen was updated immediately (The submitted profile method). I tried to create a method that does the same function I need and call it in before the notifyDataSetChanged but nothing works. Any advise on why my notifyDataSetChanged is not working would be appreciated thanks.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSubmit, adapterPending;
    ArrayList<String> itemsSubmit, itemsPending;
    ListView lstSubmitPro, lstPendingPro;
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +  "/CaptureLogs";
    Button btnSubmit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_pro_list);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
        lstSubmitPro = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstSubmitPro);
        lstPendingPro = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstPendingPro);
        itemsSubmit = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapterSubmit = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.prolist, R.id.tvRows, itemsSubmit);
        lstSubmitPro.setAdapter(adapterSubmit);
        itemsPending = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapterPending = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, itemsPending);
        lstPendingPro.setAdapter(adapterPending);
        lstPendingPro.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        pendingSubmitProfile();
        SubmittedProfile();
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SparseBooleanArray sp = lstPendingPro.getCheckedItemPositions();
            if (sp!= null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < sp.size(); i++) {
                    if (sp.valueAt(i) == true) {

                        SubmittedProfile();
                        adapterSubmit.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        itemsPending.remove(sp.get(i));
                        adapterPending.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(ProList.this, "Your profiles have been submitted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ProList.this, "Please choose a profile to be submitted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            }

        });

  public void pendingSubmitProfile()
    {
        File dir = new File(path);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                BufferedReader inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                    String lineToRead = "--PENDING SUBMIT--";
                    String CurrentLine;
                    while ((CurrentLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (CurrentLine.equals(lineToRead)) {
                            String filen = f.getName().substring(0, f.getName().lastIndexOf("."));
                            itemsPending.add(filen);

                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }




public void SubmittedProfile()
{
    File dir = new File(path);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File f : files) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            BufferedReader inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String lineToRead = "--SUBMITTED--";
                String CurrentLine;
                while ((CurrentLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (CurrentLine.equals(lineToRead)) {
                        String filen = f.getName().substring(0, f.getName().lastIndexOf("."));
                        itemsSubmit.add(filen);

                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LOG**

*Before, 2 items but 1 checked*

```
05-02 08:00:02.409 4293-4293/com.example.irambi.irmobilewizard D/returned value:: 2 1 2
```

*After, 2 items but 1 checked*

```
05-02 08:00:03.726 4293-4293/com.example.irambi.irmobilewizard D/returned value:: 0 1 0
```

*This is for 1 item and 1 checked. I cannot tell if this is before or after since theres only 1 printed on logcat. This will crash and error is as follows*

```
05-02 08:03:35.345 4293-4293/com.example.irambi.irmobilewizard D/returned value:: 1 1 1

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

*Before, 2 items but 2 checked*

```
05-02 08:07:56.378 4596-4596/com.example.irambi.irmobilewizard D/returned value:: 2 2 2
```

*After, 2 items but 2 checked* - This will crash

```
05-02 08:07:57.671 4596-4596/com.example.irambi.irmobilewizard D/returned value:: 0 2 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
```

All the testing are done using

```
itemsPending.remove(sp.keyAt(i));
                      adapterPending.remove(adapterPending.getItem(sp.keyAt(i)));
```

Log based on:

```
Log.d("returned value:", itemsPending.size() + " " + sp.size()  + " " + adapterPending.getCount());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
itemsPending.remove(sp.keyAt(i));
adapterPending.remove(adapterPending.getItem(sp.keyAt(i)));
adapterPending.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**EDIT:**

So basically the switching of list data is working fine. What's messing the code is his file writing. I resolve it this way.

First is a create a function that would update my Pending Files to submitted.

```
public void submitPendingProfile(String filename){
    try {
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path + "/" + filename+".txt"));
        String line;
        StringBuffer inputBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
            inputBuffer.append(line);
            inputBuffer.append('\n');
        }
        String inputStr = inputBuffer.toString();

        file.close();


        inputStr = inputStr.replace("--PENDING SUBMIT--", "--SUBMITTED--");

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + filename+".txt");
        fileOut.write(inputStr.getBytes());
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
    }
}
```

Then i refactor the loop for simplier process. Like removing the line `SubmittedProfile();` that keeps reading all text files if conditions is true. That is a lot of process. Here's how instead.

```
for(int i = lstPendingPro.getAdapter().getCount() - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (sp.get(i)) {
       //So when file is submitted, i update the files status using the above function.
       submitPendingProfile(itemsPending.get(i));

       //To avoid rereading of files, just add the item before removing it to the pending list
       itemsSubmit.add(itemsPending.get(i));
       adapterSubmit.notifyDataSetChanged();

       itemsPending.remove(sp.keyAt(i));
       adapterPending.notifyDataSetChanged();
       Toast.makeText(ProList.this, "Your profiles have been submitted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170256/discussion-on-answer-by-android-k-doe-android-notifydatasetchanged-not-refreshin).

Answer (score 0):

Did You tried changing your code to this order

```
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
    SparseBooleanArray sp = lstPendingPro.getCheckedItemPositions();
    if (sp != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sp.size(); i++) {
            if (sp.valueAt(i) == true) {

                SubmittedProfile();
                itemsPending.remove(sp.get(i));

                Toast.makeText(ProList.this, "Your profiles have been submitted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ProList.this, "Please choose a profile to be submitted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    adapterSubmit.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapterPending.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

});
```

Comment: Tried, but nope it still does not refresh that list instantly

Comment: Try moving the lines   
                        
                        'adapterSubmit.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    
                        itemsPending.remove(sp.get(i));
                    
                        adapterPending.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    
                        Toast.makeText(ProList.this, "Your profiles have been submitted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();'
                    

                    
                       to inside of the method SubmittedProfile()

Comment: then if I do that won't I need to declare sp again?

Comment: You can pass sp as an argument to SubmittedProfile(); by changing the method to  public void SubmittedProfile(SparseBooleanArray sp){...}

Comment: Just for getting where the issue lies

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
    itemsPending.remove(itemsPending.indexOf(sp.get(i)));
    adapterPending.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: It crashed. I got ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

```
itemsPending.remove(sp.get(i));
adapterPending.notifyDataSetChanged();
listview.invalidate();
```

Try above code might be it will help you.

Comment: Tried, but nope it still does not refresh that list instantly

Comment: Then use recylerview